# Disabled host file entry not loading

Tags: hosts, hosts-file

I have deleted an entry from my computer hosts file. So the website SHOULD be accessible BUT it is still not accessible.

I check my router URL filtering feature but there are no entries in the URL filter list.

How can I know what is blocking access to those "old" hosts file entries ? on interresting thing is that I could not access the website either from another device on the LAN

Comment: The website might just be down? Maybe actually name said website? You could use a service like [Down for everyone or just me](http://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/) to get an idea.

Answer (score 2):

Probably because the previous value (the "fake" ip-address originally in the hosts file) is still being cached/used somewhere in your computer or inside your router.
Wait a bit (usually 10 minutes) until the cache is expired and try again.
Don't keep trying in the mean time. The re-tries may cause the cached entry to remain active and thereby preventing it from expiring!

On Windows you can force the cache empty by a "ipconfig /flushdns" in a command-prompt (must be started with admin-rights).
Applications that do their own caching on a higher level (like web-browsers) may need a restart.

Rebooting the router and/or computer may also help. (Some router retain the cache across reboots, which is not helpful in this case.)

Comment: Roger that. I just tried flushdns with no success...I'll reboot all devices later to see if it works. Thanks you mate